# toggle down only one div from ng-container with *ngFor

Tags: angular, animation, togglebutton

I would like to toggle down only one div among multiple divs by clicking one of button

HTML code

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let m of images">
<button (click) = "toggle(m[m.length-1])"><img src = {{m[0]}}/></button>
   <div id = "toggle" *ngIf = "chosen" [@toggle] = 'status'>
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let z of clicked | slice: 0 : 10;"><img src = {{z}}/></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <br />
</ng-container>
```

In *ngFor = "let m of images, m is Array<`string[]`> and at index 0 image is stored and at index 1 unique id is stored. So I get that id for function, toggle(). In toggle there is another Array<`string[]`>, memberimages, that has 10 images from index 0 to 9 and have unqiue id at the last index. so compare id with id in this.memberimages and if it is same, then set chosen as true and save the matching string[] from this.memberimages to this.clicked and that is used in li tag.... hope the explanation is understandable.... :(

```
toggle(id: string){
        this.status = this.status === 'open' ? 'close' : 'open';
        if(this.status != 'close')
        {
            this.memberimages.forEach((item, index) =>{
                if(item[item.length-1] == id){
                    this.clicked = item;
                    this.chosen = true;
                    index = this.memberimages.length;
                }   
            });
        }
        else
        {
            this.chosen = false;
        }       
}
```

Animation

```
  animations:[
    trigger('toggle', [
        state('open', style({
            'opacity' : '1',
            'display' : 'block' 
        })),
        state('close', style({
            'opacity' : '0',
            'display' : 'none'
        })),
        transition('open => close', animate('1000ms ease-in-out', style({
            'opacity':'0',
            'display' : 'none'
        }))),
        transition('close => open', animate('1000ms ease-in-out', style({
            'opacity':'1',
            'display' : 'block'
        })))
    ])
]
```

CSS for div id = "toggle" is simply display: none;

what I expected was if I click one of buttons(5 in total), values should be toggled down under that button ONLY. However, what is actually happening is that once I click one of the buttons, values are correct but every button had toggled div with same values at once and I don't see any animation effect
How can I match one div one button so that each button has a right values and only toggled div?

PS: Apologize for my bad English.. :(

Comment: Please consider creating a StackBlitz Project.

Comment: oh you mean demo right? I am sorry I am new to Stackoverflow. Can you tell me how? :(

Comment: Please click on this link. It will fork a starter Angular Project for you. You can make your changes on the top of it and share it here:

https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create new variable

```
Toggle =[]
```

Then
Use index to track the element

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let m of images; let i=index ">
<button (click) = "toggle(m[m.length-1]);Toggle[i] =! Toggles[i] "><img src = {{m[0]}}/></button>
   <div id = "toggle" *ngIf = "Toggle[i]" [@toggle] = 'status'>
    <ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let z of clicked | slice: 0 : 10;"><img src = {{z}}/></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <br />
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more about your logic? :((

Comment: Since you using array of data you have no track of single element so if you use empty  array and identify each element with id you can  toggle single element instead of all elements